# Series expansion of natural log $\ln(1+1/x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm trying to get the series expansion of:

$$f(x)=\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+...$$

The series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ around zero:

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+...$$

I can't just make $\frac{1}{\hat{x}}=x$ since there is a singularity in zero, however the first series still works for $|x|\geq1$.

How can I get the expansion ?

- I know one can use Laurent series to prove it, however I want to know if there is an elementary method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion $\log (1+x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ is valid for $-1<x\le 1$.

Let $x=1/t$.  Note that $x\to 1/t$ maps $0<x\le 1$ into $t\le 1$, and maps $-1<x<0$ into $t>-1$.

Therefore, we see that the expansion $\log (1+1/t) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{t^{-n}}{n}$ is valid for $t\ge1$ and $t<-1$.

Comment: You are right , I  was confused with something else